# Declare generic provider method in dagger2

Tags: android, dagger-2, generic-programming

I have this provides method in my module in dagger 2:

```
@Provides
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter(Context context) {
    return new ArrayAdapter<>(context,R.layout.spinner_item);
}
```

and i inject it by my adapter constructor:

```
@Inject
public ReportMarhaleAdapter(ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter) {
    detailMains = new ArrayList<>();
    ciExecStatus = new ArrayList<>();
    spinnerCiStatusAdapter = arrayAdapter;
}
```

Is it possible to use generic provide method in dagger like this:

```
@Provides
ArrayAdapter<T> arrayAdapter(Context context) {
    return new ArrayAdapter<>(context,R.layout.spinner_item);
}
```

and i declare T type in constructor injection. for example :

```
 @Inject
public ReportMarhaleAdapter(ArrayAdapter<Object> arrayAdapter) {
    detailMains = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a dagger pro but, usage of `@Named` could be better instead of being generic.

```
@Provides
@Named("SomethingXToBeProvided")
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterX(Context context) {
    return new ArrayAdapter<>(context,R.layout.spinner_item);
}

@Provides
@Named("SomethingYToBeProvided")
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterY(Context context) {
    return new ArrayAdapter<>(context,R.layout.spinner_item);
}
```

Then

```
@Inject
public ReportMarhaleAdapter(
    @Named("SomethingXToBeProvided") ArrayAdapter<Object> arrayAdapterX, 
    @Named("SomethingYToBeProvided") ArrayAdapter<Object> arrayAdapterY) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, by name or qualifier it is possible but i want to know can i use generic? Or how can i implement generic way@blackkara